# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException iterating over 2D arrays in Java

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

Sorry this question can't really be applied to others. I've been looking at it for a couple hours and I still can't see it. It must  be super simple yet I can't find where I'm trying to access something that isnt there. I am getting a

> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while iterating over a 9x9 grid.

```
public ArrayList<Grid> next9Grids()
{
    ArrayList<Grid> next9 = new ArrayList<Grid>();//list of new Grids

    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; i < values[i].length; j++){
            if (values[i][j] == 0){//if empty
                for(int next = 1; next <= 9; next++){
                    Grid temp9 = new Grid(this);//need to make another grid for each #
                    temp9.values[i][j] = next; // changes value of empty space to 1->9
                    next9.add(temp9); //add grid to arrayList
                }
                return next9;
            }
        }

    }
    return null;

}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
>     at sudoku.Grid.next9Grids(Grid.java:112)    at
>   sudoku.Solver.solveRecurse(Solver.java:54)    at
>   sudoku.Solver.solveRecurse(Solver.java:56)    at
>   sudoku.Solver.solveRecurse(Solver.java:56)

This is the source of the error.(Grid.java:112) is ----> `if(values[i][j] ==0){`

Another question is Why is an error thrown on line 112 when it's accessing something that the second for loop is first iterating over and not the second for loop?

Anything is greatly appreciated. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: `i < values[i].length` should be `j < values[i].length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one :

```
for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){ 
            for(int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++){// replaced j in (i < values[i].length) by i in (j < values[i].length)
                if (values[i][j] == 0){//if empty
                    for(int next = 1; next <= 9; next++){
```

Answer (score 0):

your condition in the nested forloop is wrong. It should be `j` instead of `i`

```
public ArrayList<Grid> next9Grids()
    {
        ArrayList<Grid> next9 = new ArrayList<Grid>();//list of new Grids

        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++){
                if (values[i][j] == 0){//if empty
                    for(int next = 1; next <= 9; next++){
                        Grid temp9 = new Grid(this);//need to make another grid for each #
                        temp9.values[i][j] = next; // changes value of empty space to 1->9
                        next9.add(temp9); //add grid to arrayList
                    }
                    return next9;
                }
            }

        }
        return null;

    }
```

Comment: Thank you sorry about not making yours the answer the other guy answered quicker. Thank you for answering. Maybe someday I can help you with a problem.

Answer (score 0):

in the sixth line of you code, replace i with j

```
public ArrayList<Grid> next9Grids(){

ArrayList<Grid> next9 = new ArrayList<Grid>(); //list of new Grids

for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++){  // The change is here
        if (values[i][j] == 0){ //if empty
            for(int next = 1; next <= 9; next++){
                Grid temp9 = new Grid(this);//need to make another grid for each #
                temp9.values[i][j] = next; // changes value of empty space to 1->9
                next9.add(temp9); //add grid to arrayList
            }
            return next9;
        }
    }
}
return null;
```

}